# Error launch Unity3D 2017

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just installed Unity3D on my PC but unfortunately, I encountered a problem when launching it.

As you can see in the picture I remain stuck here:

[image: Error here]

Comment: Check your internet connection, firewall settings etc. We are not magicians we need some details.

Comment: Hi
I desactivated my firewall windows its same error, my connexion its good :)

Comment: Restart your computer ! I got the same problem yesterday, it disappeared after a reboot.